# Get Magento Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group from backend into frontend array

Tags: php, arrays, magento, object, magento-1.9

How do get the property of a Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group object into an array?  I need the _storeIds and _storeCodes into respective arrays.

```
$theobjectthathasdataiwant = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getGroupCollection();
var_dump($theobjectthathasdataiwant);
```

results in:

```
object(Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group)[129]
protected '_cacheTag' => boolean true
protected '_eventPrefix' => string 'store_group' (length=11)
protected '_eventObject' => string 'store_group' (length=11)
protected '_stores' => 
array (size=3)
  7 =>
   .....
protected '_storeIds' => 
array (size=3)
  7 => string '7' (length=1)
  4 => string '4' (length=1)
  5 => string '5' (length=1)
protected '_storeCodes' => 
array (size=3)
  7 => string 'rg' (length=2)
  4 => string 'xray' (length=4)
  5 => string 'zoe' (length=3)
protected '_storesCount' => int 3
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Got it!  As follows:

```
$theobjectthathasdataiwant = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getGroupCollection();
$Group = $theobjectthathasdataiwant[5]; //<-- [5] is the group of my desired store array
$storearrayiwant = $Group->getStoreIds();
$var_dump($storearrayiwant);
```

Finally, my store id array:

```
array (size=3)
  7 => string '7' (length=1)
  4 => string '4' (length=1)
  5 => string '5' (length=1)
```